$f:\mathbb D\subset\mathbb C\to X$ is holomorphic, then $\displaystyle\sup_f\sup_z|f'(z)|=\sup_f|f'(0)|$, where $\mathbb D$ is the unit disk.
I encountered this problem because I saw the following assertion at page 233 in Complex Differential Geometry by Fangyang Zheng:

$(X,h)$ is a Hermitian manifold. Say there is a constant $c$ such that $|f'(0)|_h\leq c$ for all holomorphic $f:\mathbb D\to X$. Since $\mathbb D$ is homogeneous (i.e. $\forall z,w\in\mathbb D$, $\exists f\in{\rm Aut}(\mathbb D)$ such that $f(z)=w$), $|f'(z)|_h\leq c$ for any holomorphic $f:\mathbb D\to X$ and any $z\in\mathbb D$.

During the process of solving the problem, I saw the following assertion at page 65 in Introduction to Complex Hyperbolic Spaces by Serge Lang:

$f:\mathbb D\to X$ is holomorphic, then $\displaystyle\sup_f\sup_z|f'(z)|=\sup_f|f'(0)|$.

My attempt:
Take $g\in{\rm Aut}(\mathbb D)$ such that $g(0)=z$, then $g(w)=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}z+w}{\bar zw+e^{i\theta}}$, and $|g'(0)|=1-|z|^2$. Then
$$|f'(z)|_h=|f'(g(0))|_h=\left|\frac{(f\circ g)'(0)}{g'(0)}\right|_h\leq\frac c{1-|z|^2}\geq c.$$
I'm stuck at the reserve inequality. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
